# Relationship between Comboboxes in C#

Tags: c#, combobox

I have 2 comboboxes.

Each of them are bounded to same Table. When I change value in one of them the other combobex appropriately changed. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Post the relevant code please.

Comment: Winforms, WPF, ASP, MVC?  What environment is the Combobox?

Answer (score 0):

Bind first ComboBox with data table then make a copy of data table in memory and bind it to the second ComboBox.

```
DataTable dataTable = db.FetchData();
ComboBox1.DataSource = dataTable;

// copying both structure and data
DataTable secondDataTable = dataTable.Copy();
ComboBox2.DataSource = secondDataTable;
```